# How do I create a line in Mapbox GL?

Tags: mapbox-gl

I'd like to draw a line in mapbox-gl.  Something like so:

```
const line = new Polyline({
  points: [
    { lat: 0, lng: 0},
    { lat: 1, lng: 1},
  ]
});
line.addTo(map);

line.remove();
```

Everywhere I search, this comes up as really complicated involving GeoJson and Layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it is very complicated and does necessitate GeoJson and Layers.  This may make it seem like you're doing something wrong.  Anyways, you can fairly easily make your own Polyline class.

```
export interface IPolylineProps {
    id: string;
    points: Array<[number, number] | { lat: number, lng: number }>
    layout?: mapboxgl.LineLayout;
    paint?: mapboxgl.LinePaint;
}

export class Polyline {
    constructor(private props: IPolylineProps) {}

    protected map: mapboxgl.Map;

    public addTo(map: mapboxgl.Map) {
        if (this.map) {
            this.remove();
        }
        this.map = map;
        map.addLayer({
            'id': this.props.id,
            'type': 'line',
            'source': {
                'type': 'geojson',
                'data': {
                    'type': 'Feature',
                    'properties': {},
                    'geometry': {
                        'type': 'LineString',
                        'coordinates': this.props.points.map((point) => {
                            return Array.isArray(point) ? point : [point.lng, point.lat]
                        })
                    }
                }
            },
            'layout': this.props.layout || {
                'line-join': 'round',
                'line-cap': 'round'
            },
            'paint': this.props.paint || {
                'line-color': '#888',
                'line-width': 3
            }
        })
    }

    public remove() {
        if (!this.map) { return; }
        this.map.removeLayer(this.props.id);
        this.map.removeSource(this.props.id);
        this.map = undefined;
    }
}
```